# Assembly: how to add two 64 bit numbers by using 16 bit registers?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I've searched for about one day but I can't find anything about adding 64 bit numbers in assembly - Nasm

How can I do this ?

My registers are only 16 bit and I have 2 numbers of 64 bits. The application I am using is Nasm. (it's for a school project)

Comment: I would think that the ADC (add-with-carry) instruction would be useful to you. Don't forget to CLC (clear carry flag) before starting.

Answer (score 3):

You have to split 64 bit numbers to 16 bit registers and then add the parts separately starting from least significant word. Note that for the higher words you have to use `adc` (add with carry) because 1 must be added to the resulting word if the previous result does not fit in 16 bits. You do not have to clear the carry flag before addition if you use normal `add` for the first word.

```
a: dq 0         ; first operand
b: dq 0         ; second operand and result

; ...

mov ax, [a]     ; bits 0..15
mov bx, [a + 2] ; bits 16..31
mov cx, [a + 4] ; bits 32..47
mov dx, [a + 6] ; bits 48..63

add [b], ax
adc [b + 2], bx
adc [b + 4], cx
adc [b + 6], dx
```